# Landsat 8 cloud band: how to understand their (bit) coding?

Tags: landsat-8, cloud-cover

I am trying to understand how to use the Lansdat 8 cloud quality band. The user guide [L8_Surface-Reflectance-Code-LASRC-Product-Guide.pdf](https://prd-wret.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/palladium/production/s3fs-public/atoms/files/LSDS-1368_%20L8_Surface-Reflectance-Code-LASRC-Product-Guide.pdf) does not explain much, but just gives tables (Table 7-1, 7-2 and 7-3) I don't really understand how to read those, and how to use them.

Could someone help walk through this table? My understanding is I need to convert the results of the pixel_qa band into bits. In R, I use `intToBits()` and get a sequence of bits, say for pixel value 388:

```r
intToBits(388)
#>  [1] 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
#> [24] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

How do I interpret this? What about the `Cloud confidence` Attribute/ Do I have to do bite addition of columns 6 and 7? I imagine also that some attribute contradict each other (cannot have clear and cloud and high cloud confidence in the same time?)

[image: Source:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use as.integer(intToBits(x))
In your example

```
as.integer(intToBits(388))
#> [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is the binary in reverse order.
In the results your bits 2, 7 and 8 area active (starts with bit 0).

This indicates that this pixel is a Water area (bit 2 active), with medium cloud confidence (bit 7 active and bit 6 not active), low confidence of being a cirrus (bit 8 active and bit 9 not active).

Maybe this Table from the documentation can help you with other cases:
[image]